# Emacs company mode inserts completion on space key pressed

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Typing text in Emacs with company-mode turned on. When I stop at the end of a word company-mode shows available completions. Because the word is already written, it does not need to be auto-completed and I want to type another word, I press space key. company-mode inserts first suggestion instead of canceling auto-completion. Is this normal? How can I make company-mode to cancel auto-completion when I insert space character?

Example:

```
This file is
```

Cursor right after "is" and company-mode shows some auto-completion suggestions. After I press space key I get:

```
This file isearch-adjusted
```

("isearch-adjusted" was the first suggestion in the tooltip of company)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the description of `company-auto-complete`, and set it to nil to disable this behavior.

It's nil by default, though, so it shouldn't have caught you unawares. Are you using someone else's Emacs config?

Comment: Thank you. I am using ergoemacs-mode (https://ergoemacs.github.io/) which modifies a portion of init file and I found 'company-auto-complete' set to non-nil in that part of the file. It is most likely that I was messing around with settings from ergoemacs interface and failed to properly undo some changes.